# jquery cycle content with a prev and next buttone

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have a jquery cycle script for my website to continually cycle through content on what's new within our company. Right not I have the transition set to scrollLeft. I would like to add a prev and next button that would scrollRight on prev and scrollLeft on next. I couldn't find any forums that would do quite what I'm looking for. Here is my code.

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    delay: -100,
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',  
})
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for more than this, but: `fx: 'scrollHorz'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the navigation, you just need to create "prev" and "next" buttons with the IDs of `prev` and `next`.

To get the reverse scrolling, you'll want to set your scroll to be `scrollHorz` and then set the `rev` option (reverse) to 1. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/g9b7k/

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz',
    delay:  -100,
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',
    rev: 1
});​
```

Comment: But will that also continue to cycle too?

Comment: It will--I updated it with a JSFiddle. Check it out and see if that's what you're looking for.